# How to stream a file (bytea) from Postgresql using Node and Angular?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, angular, download, bytea

I have an app with Angular 4 frontend and Node (express) backend. I have files (.doc, .pdf etc.) stored in postgresql as `bytea` type columns.

I would like to provide the user with a download link in the front end without storing the file temporarily in the backend server. Is it possible? Is it okay if I stream the output from the DB directly to the client and let the user download the file?